# Square root: a contraction?

Tags: real-analysis

Is the square root a contraction? If yes, there should be only one fixed point; yet, there are two of them, 0 and 1! Thanks for help!

Comment: You have essentially answered your own question.  What happens between $0$ and $1$?

Comment: But, for $x\ge 1$, it *is* a contraction.

Comment: @Berci: For $x\geq \frac{1}{4}$ it is a contraction, too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You’ve actually answered your own question: it’s not a contraction. I suspect, however, that what you’d really like is an example *showing* that it’s not a contraction. If $f(x)=\sqrt x$, how does $$\left|f\left(\frac14\right)-f(0)\right|$$ compare with $$\left|\frac14-0\right|\,?$$